# In matplotlib, how can I directly adjust the legend box size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, latex

I am using matplotlib to save the plot as svg file for my LaTeX document. I am disabling `"text.parse_math"` setting to let the text typeset while building my document (see comment).

Here is an example for my Python code (matplotlib 3.6.2):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["svg.fonttype"] = "none"
plt.rcParams["text.parse_math"] = False
plt.rcParams["axes.unicode_minus"] = False

plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], label=r"$\tilde{H}\left(t_\infty\right)$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and matplotlib shows the plot like this

[image: Plot rendered by matplotlib]

while the LaTeX shows like this

[image: Plot rendered by LaTeX]

The label in the legend is converted to math mode by LaTeX as expected. However, since the legend box size is determined by the raw label text, its width is much larger than I want it to be in LaTeX mode.

I searched for the solution but the documents and the other stackoverflow questions are all about modifying the legend artist or controlling the padding. How can I directly reduce the legend box size? Specifically, I want to know if any of these is possible and which will be the best:

1. Use something like "proxy label", i.e., make the box size adjusted to "H(t_oo)" but the real lable has longer LaTeX syntax.
2. Directly adjust the legend size from `plt.legend()`
3. Directly create `Legend()` instance with appropriate size
4. Subclass `Legend` class to define my own legend.

(edit: enhance code and specify matplotlib version)

Comment: I ran your code and could not reproduce the issue. What Matplotlib version are you using? I'm on 3.7.1.

Comment: @jared I'm using 3.6.2. If your result shows the label formatted to mathematical expression, perhaps you missed `plt.rcParams["text.parse_math"] = False` part.

Comment: I changed that to `True` to get the LaTeX result. Were you converting the label to latex using some other method?

Comment: Yes. I am letting the text formatted during building my LaTeX document, rather than pre-formatting it by matplotlib's tex engine. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597807/298357)

Comment: Oh, okay, I had misunderstood. Why don't you want to generate the plots completely in python?

Comment: The benifit is that the the texts in plots become identical (font, size, etc) to the other texts in my document. Also, it makes the texts searchable by Ctrl+F. But the drawback is, well, it makes me open this question:( I'm kinda experimenting with it, but perhaps typesetting by Python would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to create a figure that uses the LaTeX font (computer modern) and is searchable in your PDF, then you can make that directly in Matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

plt.close("all")
rc("font", **{"family":"serif","serif":["Computer Modern Roman"], "size":12})
rc("text", usetex=True)

plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], label=r"$\tilde{H}\left(t_\infty\right)$")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("temp.pdf")
plt.show()
```

Here is the result in PNG form:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solves every problem. I can even use packages like `siunitx` through `"text.latex.preamble"` rcParam.

Comment: Note for future visitor: if the figure is scaled in LaTeX document, the text size gets scaled as well. Set the appropriate figure size from the beginning and do not scale the image when imbedding it. The appropriate size may have width equal to the `\columnwidth` or `\textwidth`. Refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378178/298357 to get these values.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the legend box width, by setting a new value to `plt.legend()._legend_box.width`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["svg.fonttype"] = "none"
plt.rcParams["text.parse_math"] = True
plt.rcParams["axes.unicode_minus"] = False

plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], label=r"$\tilde{H}\left(t_\infty\right)$")
legend = plt.legend()
legend._legend_box.width = 85  # <-- Setting new width
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Option 2: Remove the legend box line

Another solution that won't require manual override of the legend box width is to completely remove it. You remove the legend box line like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["svg.fonttype"] = "none"
plt.rcParams["text.parse_math"] = True
plt.rcParams["axes.unicode_minus"] = False

plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], label=r"$\tilde{H}\left(t_\infty\right)$")
legend = plt.legend()
legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.0)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `_legend_box` does the trick.

Since setting the width of `VPacker` (returend by `_legend_box`) modifies the margin in both direction while the box is on the center on the legend item, I now want to left-align the artist. Would there also be a way to do this?